# hi ! I am new to programming ,I started learning dart to work on flutter ,my question is in while loops

Tags: flutter, dart

why when I write ex:

```
var count = 1; 
while (count < 10) {
    print(count);
    count += 1;
}
```

it displays the count from 1-10 , but if i switched the print statement with the last line it gives me a count from 2-11 even my condition is to be under 10 ! ,thank you for your time

I would appreciate any tips for learning dart and flutter as a total beginner  ,I am learning from a written course at eduactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you get values from 1-10 and 2-11?
I'd expect values from 1-9 and 2-10.
The reason is that in each loop

1. The condition is checked
2. The body of the loop is executed

So when entering the loop `count` always has a value between 1 and 9 (inclusive).
When you increase that value by one before printing it, your algorithm prints the next number, not the one it already checked against the condition. You could add a million to `count` and it would be printed, even though your algorithm would leave the loop right after.